# Visitor visa to Canada

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada

I am a crew member on board a cruise liner in the USA. I hold a C1 and B1/B2 visa. What is the procedure for me to apply for a visitor visa to Canada? Where should it be applied from? My country of nationality is India.

Can I apply online? What is the website? What is the duration of the visa?

Comment: When you say "a C1 and B1/B2 visa" do you mean for the US?

Comment: Have you looked at this website? http://www.cic.gc.ca/ENGLISH/information/applications/visa.asp

Answer (score 1):

A citizen of India who wants to visit Canada as a tourist (e.g., for a vacation) for a stay of up to six months will need a Canadian Temporary Resident/Visitor’s Visa stamped inside of his/her valid passport or other authorized travel document. There is an option to apply online (if you qualify) if you have the ability to scan the required documents and can pay the fee (around $100 CAD for an individual) by credit card; OR you can apply using a traditional paper application at an IRCC Visa Office (e.g., in a Canadian embassy or consulate) or at a Visa Application Centre (VAC). You must be in good health, have good character and meet other criteria to enter Canada, noting that this is general information based on the limited information that you provided.